# Bass: Exercise 2.5, preimages of sets in sigma algebra forms a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> **Exercise 2.5:** Let $(Y, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $f$ map $X$ into $Y$, but do not assume that $f$ is one-to-one. Define $\mathcal{B} = \{f^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal{A}\}$. Prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$.

**My work so far:**

First, notice that $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$ and since $f$ maps $X$ into $(Y, \mathcal{A})$ we have that $f(X) \in \mathcal{A}$. \

***Figure out argument for complement*** (My problem point)

Now, suppose that $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset \mathcal{B}$, that is $f(B_i) = A_i \in \mathcal{A}_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, notice that
\begin{equation*}
 f\biggr(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i\biggr) = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty f(B_i) = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{A},
\end{equation*}
since $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Therefore, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i \in \mathcal{B}$. Moreover, due to De Morgan's laws we have
\begin{equation*}
 \biggr(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty B_i \biggr)^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i \in \mathcal{B},
\end{equation*}
since $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under complement and countable union. Exploting the closure under complements again, we have that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty B_i \in \mathcal{B}$.

**My Issue:** I think I have everything figured out except for the complement. My issue stems from the fact that we may not assume that $f$ is injective. If so, it would be simple, I think
\begin{equation*}
f(B^c) = f(X \setminus B) = f(X) \setminus f(B) = f(X) \cap f(B)^c
\end{equation*}
but since it is not injective, there may be some $b \in B^c$ such that $f(b) \in f(B)$. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Preimage is compatible with complement. So if $C\in \mathcal{B}$, then $C = f^{-1}(A)$ for some $A\in \mathcal{A}$. So $X - C =  f^{-1}(Y-A)$.

Comment: I would agree with this, but we do not assume f is surjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having a bit of notational confusion. You keep referring to the images of sets, but the definition of $\mathcal{B}$ has to do with preimages, not images.

For example, you write

"First, note that $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$"

This is totally irrelevant. What you should say is:

"First, note that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$ and $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. Then $\emptyset \in \mathcal{B}$."

The proof follows quickly when you use pre-images and not images.

Comment: This completely solves my issues, yeah it follows immediately then. My only issue then is how do we deal with showing $X \in \mathcal{B}$.